# Change EC2 External IP Without Restarting?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

Hey is it possible to change the external IP address of my Amazon EC2 instance without restarting the thing?

Any help would be appreciated, the reason why I want to do this is because restarting will charge me for the full hour.

Comment: See answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29813335/82216).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can associate/disassociate an Elastic IP without restarting the EC2 instance. It can be done from the "Elatic IPs" screen of the AWS Management Console, EC2 section.

Comment: Would this get me a new external IP address if I dettached/attached the elastic IP?

Comment: To get a new IP address, disassociate the current Elastic IP, then allocate a new one and associate it with your instance. Don't forget to release the old Elastic IP, otherwise you will be charged for it.