# What is the AWS Public IP Limit? (Public IP not Elastic IP)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is there a limit to the number of Public IPs you can use for a given AWS region? (Not Elastic IPs)

Note - I know that you are limited to 5 Elastic IPs.  However, if you choose "auto assign IP" when creating and AWS instance, you are given an IP which changes on restart.  My question is what the limit is on these "Public IPs" that change every time your instance is stopped and started?

Comment: I have spent an hour googling for the answer, but all the results are about Elastic IPs not Public IPs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no limit on Public IPs that you can use in AWS. Limit is only on number of instances that you can launch and that instance limit too can be increased by contacting the AWS Support.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.  I was making a testing tool to spool up ec2 instances (centos+docker) and realized the 5 IP limit could be problematic, even if each instance was only up a short while to test pull requests.  So I think using Public IPs will be a quick fix for my issue.

Answer (score 5):

It is limited by the number of instance limit in your account and region. By default you have a limit of 20 instances/region. You can choose to launch all instances in public subnet with auto-assign-public-ip and use 20 public IPs.

For example, you requested an instance limit increase of 200 with justification and if it was approved, you can use up to 200 public IPs / region.

To view your limit: [Viewing Your Current Limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html)

Comment: So if I start and stop an instance 201 times within a month, I'm exceeding the monthly free quota of public ips?

Comment: You can start and stop an instance million times, you are using only one IP at any time. You have a limit of N number of instances whether running or stopped. There is no limit on public IP, only a limit on instances. So the number of public IPs you can have is limited by the number of running instances.

Comment: There's no limit, but be aware that if you use more than 50 public ips within a month, they will charge you 0.10$ for every extra ip. It's an important limitation if you need to start/stop a lot. I readed it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29813335/2010764

Comment: @AdrianLopez you are confusing Public IP with Elastic IP.